# Internet reachability issue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, reachability

I am using `MKNetworkKit` and using singelton class for internet availablity check. The way i am using class is:

```
+ (KCShared *)instance {
    static KCShared *object = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        object = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return object;
}

- (id) init {

    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
        [internetReachable startNotifier];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
        hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname: @"www.apple.com"];
        [hostReachable startNotifier];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    if(internetStatus == NotReachable){
        NSLog(@"Internet not available");
    }
    else    {
         NSLog(@"Internet available");
    }
}
```

And in my `appDelegate` i have added code like:

```
[KCShared instance];
```

On first run method `-checkNetworkStatus` calls. but when i tried to turn off my wifi it doesn't calls.

i don't know why its happened..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for init

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
        internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
        [internetReachable startNotifier];
        hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname: @"www.apple.com"];
        [hostReachable startNotifier];
         }
        return self;
   }
```

`